# Trying to run friendly-pix web (firebase sample project) with no success | functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

Tags: node.js, macos, firebase

I am trying to run [friendlypix-web](https://github.com/firebase/friendlypix-web) on a mac and for the life of me, just cannot get thru all of the readme without absurd amounts of errors and inevitable failure.

- I have tried changing the packcage-lock.json to avoid the har-validator. It sorta works until it doesn't.
- I have tried researching the error messages and tried everything, literally everything that comes up via google

full log below

```
Erics-MBP:friendlypix-web er-c.macbook$ firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'friendly-pix-a6d77'...

i  deploying database, storage, functions, hosting
Running command: npm --prefix functions install
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/er-c.macbook/friendlypix-web/functions/node_modules/.staging/base64-js-475c01ae/package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/er-c.macbook/friendlypix-web/functions/node_modules/.staging/base64-js-475c01ae/base64js.min.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/er-c.macbook/friendlypix-web/functions/node_modules/.staging/base64-js-475c01ae/index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/er-c.macbook/friendlypix-web/functions/node_modules/.staging/base64-js-475c01ae/LICENSE'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/er-c.macbook/friendlypix-web/functions/node_modules/.staging/mime-db-e4d0f48d/HISTORY.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/er-c.macbook/friendlypix-web/functions/node_modules/.staging/base64-js-475c01ae/README.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/er-c.macbook/friendlypix-web/functions/node_modules/.staging/mime-db-e4d0f48d/index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/er-c.macbook/friendlypix-web/functions/node_modules/.staging/mime-db-e4d0f48d/LICENSE'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/er-c.macbook/friendlypix-web/functions/node_modules/.staging/mime-db-e4d0f48d/README.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/er-c.macbook/friendlypix-web/functions/node_modules/.staging/node-forge-c488a5e7/dist/forge.min.js.map'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/er-c.macbook/friendlypix-web/functions/node_modules/.staging/node-forge-c488a5e7/dist/prime.worker.min.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/er-c.macbook/friendlypix-web/functions/node_modules/.staging/protobufjs-c4159c54/dist/light/protobuf.js.map'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/er-c.macbook/friendlypix-web/functions/node_modules/.staging/node-forge-f0c18692/dist/forge.min.js.map'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/er-c.macbook/friendlypix-web/functions/node_modules/.staging/@firebase/database-07a29a46/dist/index.node.cjs.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/er-c.macbook/friendlypix-web/functions/node_modules/.staging/node-forge-f0c18692/dist/prime.worker.min.js'
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/har-validator/-/har-validator-5.1.2.tgz
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'har-validator@5.1.2' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'functions'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/er-c.macbook/.npm/_logs/2019-06-12T18_47_15_351Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

I just want to install and then deploy this with success.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you :)

`npm ERR! 404  'har-validator@5.1.2' is not in the npm registry.`

if you check [this](https://github.com/ahmadnassri/node-har-validator/issues/113), there is an error with that package version, probably update it `5.1.3` and try again should do the trick if everything else is fine.

Take a look!

Comment: thank you, even when I overcome that error, still no dice

Comment: I used the solution [here by cdimascio](https://github.com/ahmadnassri/node-har-validator/issues/113)

Comment: I have not successfully run this. I meant to say, I tried the solution, not successfully